# Handle Enter to change value of edit control in MFC

Tags: mfc

I use edit control to display input value in MFC. That value is used in a while loop to calculate other parameters. When using EN_CHANGE to update data value, I can not use float input number.  How can I actually change that value after hit "Enter" key?

```
    float m_ini_gainG;  // m_ini_gainG is value of edit Control.


    void CMy0Dlg::OnClickedPlay()
    {
       m_thread = AfxBeginThread(MainThread,this); 
    }


    UINT CMy01Dlg::MainThread(LPVOID pParam)
    {
      CMy01Dlg *pMainDlg = (CMy01BayerToRGBDlg*)pParam;
      while(1)
       {
        pMainDlg->m_iTimer = pMainDlg->SetTimer(DISPLAY, 10, 0);

       }
      return 0;
    }



    void CMy01BayerToRGBDlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
    {

      if(nIDEvent == DISPLAY)
      {
        Read(data); // data is read continuously
        ......
        gainB = temp_G*m_ini_gainG/temp_B;
        m_gainB.Format(L"%0.2f",gainB);
        UpdateData(FALSE);
     }
    CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
    }



    void CMy01BayerToRGBDlg::OnChangeIniG()
    {

     UpdateData(TRUE);
    }
```

I can only set integer value for m_ini_gainG. I can not enter "." to set float value.

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have (only relevant part) and what do you mean "can not use float input number"?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, here is a link showing how to do it: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-efficiently-allow-decimal-values-in-a-Edit-control-in-MFC-1775.php

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop in the thread to invoke the timer?

Comment: Did you check on the resources if the edit control has the Number property set to True? This is equivalent to add a ES_NUMBER option in its file line.

Comment: it is not clear what is you real problem. Is it that you can not input a float number value or is it that you want to process the Enter key?

Comment: If you want to process Enter key, you will need to derive a class from `CEdit`; then in its message map add an `ON_WM_GETDLGCODE()` entry   and implement the respective `OnGetDlgCode` method, making it return the `result | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS` (notice the BIT-OR operator).